# Google places javascript library to search for places inside my database

Tags: google-places

I have a mysql database with places.Each place has a longitude/latitude.
What I want is to search for places inside an area, e.g. places inside London.
Is this possible to do with the Google places javascript library?
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of this and more is possible using the [Google Places JavaScript library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places).

There's a code snippet on the page above that does exactly that (searching for places based on longitude / latitude).

```
var map;
var service;
var infowindow;

function initialize() {
  var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433,151.1956316);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: pyrmont,
      zoom: 15
    });

  var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: '500',
    types: ['store']
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i];
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it works out for you ! :)